# Unable to push to array ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am new to ionic.

I want to push data to my array of myForm, but it is showing error **Cannot read property 'push' of undefined**

Here is my form:

public myForm: FormGroup;

```
constructor(){
     this.myForm = this._fb.group({

       docs: this._fb.array([
        this._fb.group({

          docName: [''],
          ref_array: this._fb.array([
            this._fb.group({
              refTextBox: []
            })
          ])

        }),
      ]),
     })

}
```

I want to push element to `ref_array`

here is my code:

```
    const control2 = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['docs']
    const control3 = <FormArray>control2.controls['ref_array']

    control3.push(
      this._fb.group({
        refTextBox: []
      })
    )
```

**Where i am making mistake?
*Please help and thanks in advance!***

Comment: It means control3 is undefined. Can you log control3 and paste the output here?

Comment: yes it shows, `control3 is undefined` now how do i get value `ref_array` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to maintain index for formArray:

Reference Example ---> [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactiveform-nested-array-eytkzfdata)

> Please Refer Demo it will help you to understand form array

```
 add(index){
    const control =  <FormArray>this.myForm.get('docs')['controls'][index].get('ref_array');
    control.push(
      this._fb.group({
        refTextBox: []
      })
    )
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

use `_fb.array` instead of normal Array `[]`

```
refTextBox: this._fb.array([])


let data = <FormArray>this.myForm.get('docs');
      let newdata = <FormArray>data.controls[0].get('ref_array');
      newdata.push(this._fb.group({
        refTextBox: []
      }))
```

Comment: showing some different error after adding `_fb.array` on  constructor

Answer (score 0):

probably `control2.controls['ref_array']` returns null.

add if condition

```
  if(control3 && control3.length >= 0){
   control3.push(
      this._fb.group({
        refTextBox: []
      })
    )
  }
```